# QNetworkAccessManager::setProxy example

Tags: qt, proxy

may someone give an example of using properly QNetworkAccessManager::setProxy, i meant i primaly a java developer mostly using HttpClient all the time.
Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ricardo, in Qt source code directory go to "examples/declarative/cppextensions/networkaccessmanagerfactory" or go to http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.7/examples/declarative/cppextensions/networkaccessmanagerfactory. There is nothing complicated in that class method so you should be able to use it.